Am I using FCM legacy api or Http v1?
if (hisFcmToken) {
    // Send preload silent notification
    const dataNotification= {
        data: {
            name: "Some name",
            married : 'true'
        },
        token: hisFcmToken
    };

    try {
        await admin.messaging().send(dataNotification);
        console.log(`FCM data notification sent successfully to user ${document.id}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to send FCM data notification to user ${document.id}: ${error}`);
    }

    if (someCondition)) {

        // Send user joined notification
        const userJoinedNotification = {
            notification: {
                title: `${newUserName} just joined `,
                image: someImageurl

            },
            data: {
                newUserJoinNotification: 'true'

            },
            android: {
                priority: "high"
            },
            apns: {
                headers: {
                    'apns-priority': '10'
                }
            },
            token: hisFcmToken
        };

        await admin.messaging().send(userJoinedNotification)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('Successfully sent user join notification:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending user join notification:', error);
                if (error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                    // Remove the invalid token from your database
                }
            });

I am a little bit confused about whether I am using Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) or Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) since I have to migrate to Firebase Cloud Messaging API (HTTP v1) by 6/20/2024.
The documentation says:

In place of the server key string used in legacy requests, HTTP v1 send requests require an OAuth 2.0 access token. If you are using the Admin SDK to send messages, the library handles the token for you.

But still I am not sure. Thanks.

You're using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js. As long as you're on a recent version, that's using the latest API endpoints already.
For example, here's how most of the Admin SDK determines the API to call: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/67151e620fbb7bdfc2a017e9a35d51eca035d824/src/messaging/messaging.ts#L822
this.urlPath = `/v1/projects/${projectId}/messages:send`;


I have initializing firebase admin by const admin = require('firebase-admin'); const { log } = require('firebase-functions/logger'); admin.initializeApp(); and not adding projectId anywhere inside my cloud functions and then deploying that function in the same firebase project which my android app is using. Does the admin sdk figure out projectId somehow ex: the firebase project it is deployed in? and How can I know the version of admin sdk that I am using? By the way Thank you so much @Frank

The Admin SDK can typically infer the project ID from its context. You can find the version of the Admin SDK in your package.json. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

From my package.json I got "dependencies": {     "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",     "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"   },. Firebase admin 11.8.0 uses  FCM legacy api or Http v1? Or should I migrate to the latest 12.1.0 version?

As I said, all recent versions should work fine. That line I included in my answer was last modified 5 years ago: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blame/67151e620fbb7bdfc2a017e9a35d51eca035d824/src/messaging/messaging.ts#L822. --- Note that there really isn't much more we can do here on Stack Overflow. Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Looks like v9 and some of v8 and later of the admin SDK should be fine based on that. I am running v9.12.0 https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin?activeTab=versions
